# How to style this kind of Text Field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to style this kind of TextField.

[image: TextField_Picture]

The main problem that I'm facing is to design the US$ part in leading the TextField. This is my code so far.

```
/// My Place Bid Text Field
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              child: Container(
              //width: mySize.width * 0.2,
              //height: 50,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey[200]),
                child: Text(
                  "RS \u20B9",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    labelText: "Place Bid",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Which gives me output

[image: required_output_image]

I know this question is not that complicated, but I'm still relatively new to flutter so your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey[500],
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    height: 50,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        "RS \u20B9",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "Enter Bid",
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                        )))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your solution.
Notice the "IntrinsicHeight" widget. It makes all the children inside the child the same size (depending on the biggest one). The "Center" widget inside the prefix makes the Container go max height + center the text inside of it. Just make sure not to use IntrinsicHeight too much, since the docs state that it's a bit resource heavy.

[image: Example]

```dart
Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                ),
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          border: Border(
                            right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'RS \u20B9',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            labelText: "Place Bid",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

---

The second code is almost the same, except there's no label after typing the text inside the TextField.

```dart
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                ),
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          border: Border(
                            right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'RS \u20B9',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20.0,
                              vertical: 20.0,
                            ),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: "Place Bid",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prefixIcon` to add a widget at the beginning of the textfield:

```
      Container(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                   prefixIcon: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2.0),
  child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey[200]),
                child: Text(
                  "RS \u20B9",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ),
              ),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Hint Text',
        
      ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

example:

https://dartpad.dev/a89aff20d67e2cb31da6a07ba7c17910

Answer (score 0):

```
    Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    
    ),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          child: Container(
          //width: mySize.width * 0.2,
          //height: 50,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
           border:Border.all(color:Colors.grey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                  bottomLeft:Radius.circular(4),
                ),
                color: Colors.grey[200]),
            child: Text(
              "RS \u20B9",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(

     borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                  bottomRight: 
            Radius.circular(4),
                ),
                 ),
              isDense: true,
           
                labelText: "Place Bid",
                labelStyle: 
             TextStyle(fontSize:24)),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```